# How to get the name of audio playing in a Chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, youtube-data-api, web-audio-api

We are developing a Chrome Extension, and we are trying to figure out how to get the name of the audio that is currently playing in Chrome. We know that when audio plays in Chrome, there is an icon that shows the name of the audio playing. An example of this is illustrated in the screenshot below, in which there is a video called "Chrome and the web in 2020" playing.
[image]

Is there any way that we can get the title of the video playing (which is "Chrome and the web in 2020" for this example) through our Chrome Extension? We want our extension to be able to know what video or song that the user is listening to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation of the [Video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource), the title of a given YouTube video is to be found as value of the property [`snippet.title`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.title).

This property (an any other belonging to the video resource) can be queried from the API through its [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint.

For example, issuing `curl` on the following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=$APP_KEY&id=14pb8t1lHws&part=snippet&fields=items/snippet/title&maxResults=1`

will invoke the endpoint that'll produce a [JSON response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#response) text containing only that video's title:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Chrome and the web in 2020"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For what concerns a Javascript [`GAPI`](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) (i.e. Google’s Client Library for Browser-side JavaScript) implementation, the code would look like:

```
var app_key = ...;
var videoTitle;

function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    getVideoTitle('14pb8t1lHws');
  });
}

function getVideoTitle(videoId) {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
    id: videoId,
    part: 'snippet',
    fields: 'items/snippet/title',
    key: app_key
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    if ('error' in response) {
      displayMessage(response.error.message);
    } else {
      videoTitle = response.items[0].snippet.title;
    }
  });
}
```

Note that the code above uses the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to obtain from the `Videos.list` endpoint only the video's title (it a good practice to ask from the API only the info that is of actual use).

Also note that `$APP_KEY` and `app_key` are (shell and, respectively, Javascript) variables set to contain a valid API key associated to a project created by means of [Google's developers console](http://console.cloud.google.com/).